# sqlparametersource refresh data

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using spring-integration-jdbc database listener

which will query against the database forever, the configuration is like below

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="listener"
    channel="target" 
    data-source="dataSource"
    query="select * from view1 where type='ABCD' and date=:newDate"
    selec-sql-paramater-source="parameterList"
    auto-startup="true">

        <integration:poller>
            <integration:interval-trigger interval="100000"/>
        </integration:poller>

    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<integration:splitter input-channel="chone" output-channel="chtwo"/>
<integration:service-activator input-channel="chone" ref="myclass" method="mymethod"/>

<integration:channel id="chone"/>
<integration:channel id="chtwo"/>

<bean id="parameterList" class="com.my.package.mySqlParamenterSource">
<property name="newDate"  value="${date}"/>
</bean>
```

I want newDate parameter in the query to be refreshed everyday automatically.. without restarting the application.. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already have a custom parameter source, simply have it return the appropriate date whenever getValue("newDate") is called.

Or, you can get more sophisticated by using runtime SpEL expressions.